# Mongoose wait on async func that is executed in pre-save hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to wait on the results of an async func that runs inside the pre save middleware of my model. Something like this (this code snippet is not correct but it gives an idea of what I want):

```
myModel.pre('save', (next, myCb) => {
  doSomePreSaveAsyncTask().then(myCb);
  next();
});


// ... somewhere else
anInstanceOfMyModel.save((err, savedInstance) => {
  /* this is the normal .save callback, this isn't my focus */
}, () => {
  /* this func is "myCb" above i.e. it gets supplied to the pre-save middleware */
  doStuffAfterThePreSaveAsyncTaskIsComplete();
})
```

In summary, ***at the time that I save a change***, I want to then wait on the completion of an associated async task which currently runs inside the pre-save middleware. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I don't want the async func to delay the execution of `next()`. So something like

```
doSomePreSaveAsyncTask.then(() => {
  myCb();
  next();
});
```

is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await syntax to achieve your goal. Don't forget to wrap the async call into a try/catch block:

```
mySchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  try {
    const response = await asyncCallHere();
    // do stuff with the response here
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized I didn't specify that I don't want the async func to delay the pre-save code at all. Your answer prevents the next middleware from being invoked until the async func has completed, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Also your answer doesn't show how I'll pass a callback into the pre-save middleware. That's the precise problem I'm trying to solve. `asyncCallHere` is a function that cannot be known ahead of time. It's only known at the moment that the `.save()` method is called, so I can't define it inside the pre-save middleware.

Comment: You can invoke any function inside the .pre() save hook. I can't understand what you mean by " a function that cannot be known ahead of time", please expound.

Comment: Please have another look at the code snippet I posted. `myCb` is the function that needs to wait on `doSomePreSaveAsyncTask`, and `myCb` is only known when calling `.save()`. So at that point I need to pass `myCb` into the pre-save middleware.

Comment: I just looked at your edit. Try calling `next()` before your async calls, it should work. Let me know.

Comment: The problem isn't so much when `next` is called, it's that I don't know how to pass `myCb` into the middleware func from the place where I call `.save()`. That's the core problem. The part about `next()` was to make it clear that the async func isn't intended to delay the normal process of saving the changes to the document.

Comment: I see... I don't see right now how you can achieve this in the `.pre("save")` hook. Try achieving this using the `mySchema.post("save", (doc) => {})` hook. It will run after save and you will have your function by then.